# Can you select the MIN row to display across all "Results Grid" values? (Generic Inquiry)

Tags: acumatica

I have the following tables:
(Example data)

```
PMProjects

| ContractID | ContractCD | Customer     |
| :--------  | :----------| :-------     |
| 01         | PR00001    | ABC-Customer |
| 02         | PR00002    | XYZ-Customer |
```

```
PMTasks

| Task ID  | Project ID| Task CD   | Description |
| :--------| :---------| :---------| :--------   |
| 39       | 01        | 01 First  | Zulu        |
| 40       | 01        | 02 Second | Foxtrot     |
| 41       | 01        | 03 Third  | Delta       |
| 42       | 01        | 04 Fourth | Alpha       | 
| 55       | 02        | 01 First  | Zulu        |
| 56       | 02        | 02 Second | Foxtrot     |
| 57       | 02        | 03 Third  | Delta       |
| 58       | 02        | 04 Fourth | Alpha       |
```

I have successfully joined PMTasks to PMProjects on PMProjects.ContractID = PMTasks.ProjectID.
And, I am grouping by PMProjects.ContractID

**On the GI, I need to display the MIN TaskID row for each Project.**

[My GI - Aggregate Functions by MIN value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPv9W.png)

**Result -
When I use the MIN value on the PMTasks.Description field it pulls the value "Alpha".**

```
GI Results

| ContractID | ContractCD | Customer     | Task ID  |  Task CD  | Description |
| :--------- | :--------- | :----------- | :------- | :-------- | :---------- | 
| 01         | PR00001    | ABC-Customer | 39       | 01 First  | Alpha       |
| 02         | PR00002    | XYZ-Customer | 55       | 01 First  | Alpha       |
```

[Documentation - Aggregate Function Descriptions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV0vW.png)

I see from the documentation that the MIN aggregate function, "Returns the minimum value of all values of the group."

Has anyone found a way to join many-to-one in an Acumatica Generic Inquiry using the MIN (or MAX) value of a row?
Or to put it a different way - has anyone found a way to join one of many rows to a table and have the results grid display only the values from the same row?

I hope this makes sense. Please feel free to ask any clarification questions.
Thanks for any and all feedback.

[Example GI related to the question.](https://github.com/paulgilfoy/StackOverflow---72703315/blob/09e5014c5a76fbae21e7e55031cdb3bc908a5f26/PK%20-%20Projects%204%20401k%20Summary.xml) Please excuse the error under Results Grid - PMProjects.CustomerCD_Description does not need to be aggregated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a group by PMContract.ContractID and then add the Min() function in the Data Field[image]
[image]